# Definition of transitivity of relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

We are currently learning about transitivity, and my teacher gave us the following definition: For some binary relation $R$ of type $A^2$ (so $R \subseteq A^2$ holds): $$R \ \text{is transitive} \triangleq \forall a,c \in A ( \ \exists b \in A ( \ (aRb \wedge bRc) \implies aRc \ ) \ )$$

But online, I instead find the following definition: $$R \ \text{is transitive} \triangleq \forall a,b,c \in A ( \ (aRb \wedge bRc) \implies aRc \ )$$

These are equivalent to each other? But I don't quite (intuitively) get how so. Does that then generalise to this? $$\forall a,b,c( \ P(a,b,c) \ ) \iff \forall a,c ( \ \exists b( \ P(a,b,c) \ ) \ )$$

If so, is there a proof for it?

Comment: Those statements say the same thing. That may be clearer to you if you think about what they mean in everyday English.

Comment: @EthanBolker They don't say the same thing at all; the teacher's version is plain wrong. E.g. it holds in any setting where there is some element not related to anything else. (Once you move parentheses around, though, it gets fixed.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two are not equivalent, and your teacher's (EDIT: per the OP's comment below, they miscopied the definition) proposed definition is wrong.  In particular, the property your teacher describes is automatically satisfied as soon as there is some element not related to anything (take this as your $b$, regardless of what $a$ and $c$ are).

**If you move parentheses**, though, you do get an equivalent definition, namely $$\forall a,c[\exists b(aRb\wedge bRc)\implies aRc].$$ Note that here the parentheticals following the existential quantifier do not contain the implication! I suspect that this is what your teacher meant, or that this is what your teacher actually wrote and you miscopied (either is plausible, it's an easy mistake to make). The equivalence here follows from writing the implication as a disjunction and remembering that $\exists$ is the same as $\neg\forall\neg$.

Comment: Yes this is precisely it. I have misread it as having an extra parenthesis that should not be there

Comment: @GeekOverdose Common issue!

Comment: I suggest replacing $\forall a,c[\exists b(aRb\wedge bRc)\implies aRc]$ with $\forall a,c,\, \left( \exists b,\, aRb\wedge bRc \right) \implies aRc$ since those parentheses are crucial.